# Rust creating String with pointer offset

Tags: string, pointers, rust, unsafe, raw-pointer

So let's say I have a `String`, `"Foo Bar"` and I want to create a substring of `"Bar"` without allocating new memory.

So I moved the raw pointer of the original string to the start of the substring (in this case offsetting it by 4) and use the String::from_raw_parts() function to create the String.

So far I have the following code, which as far as I understand should do this just fine. I just don't understand why this does not work.

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Foo Bar");

    let ptr = s.as_ptr();

    mem::forget(s);

    unsafe {
        // no error when using ptr.add(0)
        let txt = String::from_raw_parts(ptr.add(4) as *mut _, 3, 3);

        println!("{:?}", txt); // This even prints "Bar" but crashes afterwards

        println!("prints because 'txt' is still in scope");
    }

    println!("won't print because 'txt' was dropped",)
}
```

I get the following error on Windows:

```
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\main.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION)
```

And these on Linux (cargo run; cargo run --release):

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

free(): invalid pointer
```

I think it has something to do with the destructor of String, because as long as `txt` is in scope the program runs just fine.

Another thing to notice is that when I use `ptr.add(0)` instead of `ptr.add(4)` it runs without an error.

Creating a slice didn't give me any problems on the other Hand. Dropping that worked just fine.

```
let t = slice::from_raw_parts(ptr.add(4), 3);
```

In the end I want to split an owned String in place into multiple owned `String`s without allocating new memory.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the segments to be owned? Is it for mutability or just to avoid the lifetimes being bound to the scope of the original `String`?

Comment: Mostly because of lifetimes because the original String should be dropped after splitting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the errors is the way that the allocator works. It is *Undefined Behaviour* to ask the allocator to free a pointer that it didn't give you in the first place. In this case, the allocator allocated 7 bytes for `s` and returned a pointer to the first one. However, when `txt` is dropped, it tells the allocator to deallocate a pointer to byte 4, which it has never seen before. This is why there is no issue when you `add(0)` instead of `add(4)`.

Using `unsafe` correctly is *hard*, and you should avoid it where possible.

---

Part of the purpose of the `&str` type is to allow portions of an owned `string` to be shared, so I would strongly encourage you to use those if you can.

If the reason you can't just use `&str` on its own is because you aren't able to track the lifetimes back to the original `String`, then there are still some solutions, with different trade-offs:

1. Leak the memory, so it's effectively static:

   ```
   let mut s = String::from("Foo Bar");
   let s = Box::leak(s.into_boxed_str());

   let txt: &'static str = &s[4..];
   let s: &'static str = &s[..4];
   ```

   Obviously, you can only do this a few times in your application, or else you are going to use up too much memory that you can't get back.
2. Use reference-counting to make sure that the original `String` stays around long enough for all of the slices to remain valid. Here is a sketch solution:

   ```
   use std::{fmt, ops::Deref, rc::Rc};

   struct RcStr {
       rc: Rc<String>,
       start: usize,
       len: usize,
   }

   impl RcStr {
       fn from_rc_string(rc: Rc<String>, start: usize, len: usize) -> Self {
           RcStr { rc, start, len }
       }

       fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
           &self.rc[self.start..self.start + self.len]
       }
   }

   impl Deref for RcStr {
       type Target = str;
       fn deref(&self) -> &str {
           self.as_str()
       }
   }

   impl fmt::Display for RcStr {
       fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
           fmt::Display::fmt(self.as_str(), f)
       }
   }

   impl fmt::Debug for RcStr {
       fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
           fmt::Debug::fmt(self.as_str(), f)
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   fn main() {
       let s = Rc::new(String::from("Foo Bar"));

       let txt = RcStr::from_rc_string(Rc::clone(&s), 4, 3);
       let s = RcStr::from_rc_string(Rc::clone(&s), 0, 4);

       println!("{:?}", txt); // "Bar"
       println!("{:?}", s);  // "Foo "
   }
   ```

Comment: [Here's the source for the curious](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1233-1249) (`String::split_off` calls `Vec::split_off`).

Comment: Yeah just looked at the source as well. Is there any way to tell Rust that the offset pointer is a new pointer it can free? Also std::ptr::copy sounds promising, but doesn't work either